# Opening file on web server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I am newbie in web development. I have LAMP installed on Ubuntu 12. I have a php file "register.php" running on LAMP server which receives data from a html form and then saves it on server in a temp file. I am using below code. It does not seem to work. I've checked that it has required access and permission to execute the code but still it could not create the "temp.c"

```
$temp=fopen("temp.c","w");
$line = fgets($temp)
fclose($temp);
```

Additional Note(s):-
I am able to receive other data from the form fields but only creation of file does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are opening temp.c as a write operation, then you are trying to read from the file handle. However, just opening the file as you did in the first line should have created the file. Are you getting anything in the error logs?

Comment: Okay you are missing the semi-colon after the fgets function. That will atleast create a file for you. Rest look into AndrewR comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Semicolon after fgets function like

```
$temp=fopen("temp.c","w");
$line = fgets($temp);
fclose($temp);
```

I worked as i verified on my local server....

My advice to you is to use NETBEANS IDE for PHP development as it will display Syntax errors automatically, when you are writing the code.....

To insert form data in file use following code

```
    $entry=$_POST["myvar"];
    $file="temp.c";
    $open=fopen($file,"a");

    if($open){        
      fwrite($open,$entry);
        fclose($open);
    }
```

**'a'** in fopen($file,"a") Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

**'a+'** in fopen($file,"a+") Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

**'w'** in fopen($file,"a+") Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and ==>**truncate the file to zero length**<==. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Consult [this for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: thanks! but my point is that fopen should create the file. but it is not able to create, When it gets called by my home page(index.html which contains the form). However when I execute the same script locally through my terminal, it does create the file. So, I am stuck that why it does not work when executed indirectly through index.html?

Comment: Ur PHP code must be in .php file not in .html file
If you are posting form in index.html to itself then it will not execute

However you can make form in index.html but should Post on some .php File.......

Comment: Actually I am doing the later.. my index.html is posting form data to "register.php" using POST submission. As I mentioned initially, the php script is able to get data form data from index.html but when I try using fopen to save the form data in a file.. fopen itself fails..hope this clarifies my issue

Comment: Then there is some thing wrong in before this script in register.php file...... It might generate some fatal error and it will then stops further execution of code...
Edit the question and paste ur code inside register.php

Comment: One more thing change fopen($file, "w")  to fopen($file, "a") as now to append data in file which was created earlier....
Hope this helps

Comment: @Vishal, be sure to mark his answer as your solution so that future people might be able to search and find this.